# Swap method not working?

Tags: java

```
public class QuickSort {
    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] table, int first, int last) {

        T pivot = table[first];
        int up = first;
        int down = last;
        do {
            while ((up < last) && (pivot.compareTo(table[up]) >= 0)) {
                up++;
            }
            while (pivot.compareTo(table[down]) < 0) {
                down--;
            }
            if (up < down) {
                swap(table, up, down);
            } 
        }while (up < down);
        swap(table, first, down);
        return down;
    }

    public static void swap(int A[], int x, int y){
        int temp = A[x];
        A[x] = A[y];
        A[y] = temp;

    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with `int A[]`, but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: What problem are you having, specifically? Your logic of your swap method is correct, the implementation is not.

Comment: @Jeffrey My program says that T[] cannot be converted to int[] where T is type variable. I try changing int A[] in my swap method to T[] and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` is of type `T[]` (implicitly object array) and your swap method wants `int[]`.

Change swap to:

```
public static void swap(Object A[], int x, int y){
    Object temp = A[x];
    A[x] = A[y];
    A[y] = temp;

}
```